# How to remove 'all other' files for copy/template modules in ansible?

Tags: ansible

Small task:

```
- name: Configure hosts
  template: src=host.cfg.j2 dest=/etc/shinken/hosts/{{item.host_name}}.cfg
  with_items: shinken_hosts
  when: shinken_hosts is defined
  notify: reload config
```

I want to remove all other configs (files) in /etc/shinken/hosts/  configured by this task.

How can I do this?

(It is really important if I fix a typo in 'shinken_hosts', and want to automatically remove old config with mistake in the name).

Comment: Please provide examples. Which files must be removed and which not

Comment: shinken_hosts: host1, host2. Content of /etc/shinken/hosts/host1.cfg host2.cfg other_host.cfg, garbage.cfg.  host1&host2 should stay, other_host & garbage should be removed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you might want to check [this](http://www.slideshare.net/bcoca/ansible-tips-tricks), slide 19.
This assumes that you know what files needs to exist in the specific dir, and then deletes all others.

```
# tidy_expected: [‘conf1.cfg’, conf2.cfg’]
- find: paths={{tidy_path}} #/etc/myapp
  register: existing

- file: path={{item.path}} state=absent
  when: item.path|basename not in tidy_expected
  with_items: “{{existing.files|default([ ])}}”
  register: removed

- mail: body=“{{removed}}”
```

Comment: Yes. Looks like a fine solution.