# ansible playbook iteration through dictionary

Tags: ansible

I have ansible runbook to apply changes in DNS entries to multiple name servers.

Information about domains are stored in a list of dictionaries like this:

```
domains: [
  {
    domain: "domain.me",
    location: "default",
    ip: "XX.XX.XX.XX",
    <..>
  },
```

I managed to build a task which successfully generates zone files. But I also need to clean up the old files for domains which were removed. Though I'm not sure how I can iterate through such a list in a task. I managed to build something like this:

```
- name: Check for available configuration
  shell: ls -1 /etc/bind/zones/{{ location }}/ 
  register: contents

- name: Cleanup old files
  file: path=/etc/bind/zones/{{ location }}/{{ item }} state=absent
  with_items: "{{ contents.stdout_lines }}"
  when: item not in domains
```

Though obviously it simply deletes all the files and generates it from scratch.
Is there a way to iterate through the list of dictionaries somehow without building a separate list with duplicate information in vars?

Answer (score 0):

Would [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33026453/2599522) be of any help to you ? 
Its basically removing all files that are not part of a list (that you can generate from the config you have)

```
# tidy_expected: [‘conf1.cfg’, conf2.cfg’]
- find: paths={{tidy_path}} #/etc/myapp
  register: existing

- file: path={{item.path}} state=absent
  when: item.path|basename not in tidy_expected
  with_items: “{{existing.files|default([ ])}}”
  register: removed

- mail: body=“{{removed}}”
```

Comment: well, thank you for your answer, though it is almost en exact copy from the code I've posted in the question. the thing is that I have a list in a dictionary. that's the thing I'm stack in. I can't understand how I can iterate through specific field in dictionary..

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [map](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#map) filter to reduce your list of dictionaries into a list of strings, based on a single attribute of the dicts, in this case `domain`.

```
when: item not in domains|map(attribute='domain')|list
```